# How do you show that $||.||: N \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as below defines a norm on $N?$

Tags: functional-analysis

We are give $||x|| \ge 0$ for all $x \in N$ and $=0$ iff $x=0$, and

$||\alpha x||= |\alpha | ||x||$ for all $x \in N$ and scalars.

So we have that the first and seconds condition for a norm holds. I need help with the triangle ineq. given only that 
$\{x \in N : ||x|| \le 1\}$ is a convex subset of N.

Comment: Have you heard of Minkowski functionals?

Comment: @DanielFischer Had not until you mentioned them.

Comment: Ah, well, doesn't make much of a difference. You would have seen the argument already if you had. If $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, it is clear that $\lVert x + y\rVert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert$. so assume $\lVert x\rVert > 0,\, \lVert y\rVert > 0$. You need to show that $$\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert}\cdot (x+y) \in B = \{z\in N : \lVert z\rVert \leqslant 1\}.$$ For that, you use the convexity.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you please write an answer to this? This isn't my homework, I just need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle inequality is clear from $\lVert 0\rVert = 0$ if $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, so we need only consider the case $x\neq 0 \neq y$. Let's denote $B := \{ z \in N : \lVert z\rVert \leqslant 1\}$.

By the homogeneity and non-negativity of $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$, we have

$$\biggl\lVert \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert}\cdot x\biggr\rVert = \biggl\lvert \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert}\biggr\rvert\cdot \lVert x\rVert = \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert}\cdot\lVert x\rVert = 1,$$

so $\lVert x\rVert^{-1}\cdot x \in B$. By the same reasoning, $\lVert y\rVert^{-1}\cdot y \in B$. Since

$$\frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert} + \frac{\lVert y\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert} = 1$$

and both terms are positive, the convexity of $B$ now yields

$$B \ni\frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert}\cdot (\lVert x\rVert^{-1}\cdot x) + \frac{\lVert y\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert}\cdot (\lVert y\rVert^{-1}\cdot y) = \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert}\cdot (x+y).$$

By definition of $B$ that means

$$1 \geqslant \biggl\lVert \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert}\cdot (x+y)\biggr\rVert = \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert}\cdot \lVert x+y\rVert,$$

which upon multiplication with $\lVert x\rVert + \lvert y\rVert$ yields the triangle inequality

$$\lVert x+y\rVert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert$$

for the case $x \neq 0 \neq y$.